# XPath error trying to determine if there is atleast one child node that is not empty (has string value)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have this VB code snippet:

```
If (bAYFM = False) Then
    If (Not IsNothing(pTeaching)) Then
        ' AJT 2021.04.21.0 JIRA GCI 2
        Dim pTeachingNamesList = pTeaching.SelectNodes("Names/Name != ''")
        If (pTeachingNamesList.Count > 0) Then
            bAYFM = True
        End If
    End If
End If
```

But I am getting an exception:

> 2021-04-25  09:29:43.5244|ERROR|GoogleAuthandSync.Program|AddEventsToCalendarXML|System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
> Expression must evaluate to a node-set.    at
> System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)    at
> System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(String xpath)    at
> System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes(String xpath)

My XML is a simple array:

```
<Names>
  <Name>Text 1</Name>
  <Name>Text 2</Name>
  <Name>Text 3</Name>
</Names>
```

This is a child of the `<Teaching>` element. I was simply trying to determine if atleast one name element was not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the VB XPath API has a way of evaluating an XPath expression that returns a boolean rather than a node-set, but the minimum change to your query would be

```
pTeaching.SelectNodes("Names/Name[. != '']")
```

Comment: My `if` was testing the `Count` from the returned node set as I understand it that the `SelectNodes` method will return an empty list if no items matched the path. Using your updated path has stopped the exception. Thank you!